# Aggregate query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

This is the question to asked me to write a simple aggregate query to display the data, I'm kind of confusing. Could you please help me take a look at this code?

How can I query the data from :

```
{
        "_id": "5af50e729ba1ae0056dbb436",
        "__v": 0,
        "asset_id": "CHMHCj-sqJdbPwDs_6Y4_Q",
        "asset_type": "youtube_channel",
        "created_at": "2018-05-11T03:30:58.487Z",
        "schema_version": 1,
        "stat": "posts_30d",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-11T03:30:58.487Z",
        "value": "0"
    },
```

to:

```
[
  {
    _id: '<channel_id>',
    subscribers: [
      {value: Number, date: Date},
      // most recent 10 records
    ],
    posts_30d: [
      {value: Number, date: Date},
      // most recent 10 records
    ]
  },
]
```

for the channel_id is the asset_id and the posts_30d is the stat value. The stat value will be either "stat": "posts_30d", or "stat": "subscribers".  for the new data will display according to the asset_id, and stat value.

I have tried using unwind and project, but it doesn't look the same. Also, I use "Limit" to limit the number of the post, but the result displays should have 10 each, but it shows 10 in total.

```
db.Stats.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$stat" },
    { $sort: { updated_at: -1 } },
    { $limit : 5 },
    {
      $project: {
        asset_id: 1,
        value: 1,
        updated_at: 1,
        stat: 1
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$asset_id",
        sub: {
          $push: {
            value: "$value",
            date: "$updated_at"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]).exec(function(err, found) {
    // Log any errors if the server encounters one
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    // Otherwise, send the result of this query to the browser
    else {
      res.json(found);
    }
  });
```

Comment: could you explain where the data of channel_id, subscribers and posts_30d comes from. 
A little background, it's hard for me to understand what you are trying to project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, for the channel_id is the asset_id and the posts_30d is the stat value. The stat value will be either "stat": "posts_30d", or "stat": "subscribers".  for the new data will display according to the asset_id, and stat value.